# Subset Sum problem with many divisibility conditions

Tags: complexity-theory, number-theory, knapsack-problems

How does the computational complexity of the Subset Sum problem depend on the parameter $\alpha(S)$ of the input $(S, t)$,
defined as follows?

Considering $S$ under the divisibility partial order, i.e. $s_1 \prec s_2 \iff s_1 \mid s_2$, define

$\qquad\qquad \displaystyle \alpha(S) = \max \{|V| \mid V\subseteq S, V$ an [antichain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichain)$\}$

to be the maximum size of any subset of $S$ whose elements are pairwise relatively prime.

Subset Sum instances with $\alpha(S)=1$ are solvable in polynomial time. For example, if $S$ contains only powers of two, then $\alpha(S) = 1$, and an instance with set $S$ and any target $t$ is solvable in polynomial time.

In fact, when $\alpha(S)=1$, even the (harder) Knapsack problem is known to be solvable in polynomial time.<sup>$\dagger$</sup>

Are all Subset Sum instances with, say, $\alpha(S) = O(1)$ solvable in polynomial time?

---

$\dagger$ [Solving sequential knapsack problems](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0167-6377(93)90044-H) by M. Hartmann and T. Olmstead (1993)

---

Comment: Instead of "relation", I suggest using the terms "partial order". Also, on minimal thought, the Frobenius coin problem _might_ be relevant (of course, not sure, though)

Answer (score 4):

This problem can be **solved in polynomial time** using linear programming, and this is actually true for any partial order $(S,\le)$. By the way, we can prove by induction that for any finite partial order set  $(S,\le)$, there exists a finite set $S'\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ and a bijection $f:S\rightarrow S'$, such that for all $s_1,s_2\in S, s_1\le s_2 \Leftrightarrow f(s_1) | f(s_2)$.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the set formed by the chains in $S$. Remind that $C$ is a *chain* iff for all $v,v'$ in $C$, $v\le v'$ or $v'\le v$

Now create a boolean variable $x_v$ for each $v\in S$, and a boolean variable $y_C$ for each chain $C$. We can write the following linear program $(P)$ for our problem :
$$
\begin{split}
\text{Max} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{v\in S} x_v \\
\text{subject to} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{v\in C} &x_v \le 1, \forall C\in\mathcal{C}\\
                                         &x_v \in \{0,1\}, v\in S
\end{split}
$$

and its dual $(D)$  :

$$
\begin{split}
\text{Min} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{C\in \mathcal{C}} y_C\\
\text{subject to} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{C:v\in C} &y_C \ge 1, \forall v\in S\\
                                         &y_C \in \{0,1\}, C\in \mathcal{C}
\end{split}
$$

Then the problem of finding the minimum cover of an ordered set by chains is the dual of our problem. [Dilworth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem) states that

*There exists an antichain A, and a partition of the order into a family P of chains, such that the number of chains in the partition equals the cardinality of A*

which means that the optimal solution of these two problems match : $Opt(P)=Opt(D)$

Let $(P^*)$ (*resp.* $(D^*)$) be the relaxation of $(P)$ (*resp.* $(D)$) *i.e.* the same linear program where all constraints $x_v\in\{0,1\}$ (*resp.* $y_C\in\{0,1\}$) are replaced by $x_v\in [0,1]$ (*resp.* $y_C\in [0,1]$). Let $Opt(P^*)$ and $Opt(D^*)$ be their optimal solutions. Since $\{0,1\}\subseteq [0,1]$ we have :
$$
Opt(P)\le Opt(P^*) \text{ and } Opt(D^*)\le Opt(D)
$$
and weak duality theorem establishes that $Opt(P^*)\le Opt(D^*)$ then by putting everything together we have :
$$
Opt(P)= Opt(P^*)=Opt(D^*)=Opt(D)
$$

Then, using [Ellipsoid method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid_method), we can compute $Opt(P^*)$ ( $=Opt(P)$) in polynomial time. There are an exponential number of constraints but there exists a polynomial time separation oracle. Indeed given a solution $X$, we can enumerate all couples $s_1,s_2\in X$ and check if $s_1\le s_2$ or $s_2\le s_1$, and therefore decide in polynomial time whether $X$ is feasible or otherwise the constraint associated to the chain $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is violated.

Comment: Ellispoid method works whatever the number of constraints, if we have (1) a polynomial number of variables and (2) a *separation oracle* which given any solution $x$ decides in polynomial time whether $x$ is feasible or find a constraints violated by $x$. I recommend reading [http://www-math.mit.edu/~goemans/18433S09/ellipsoid.pdf], wikipedia is not very clear on this point

Comment: Thanks for explaining why the exponential number of constraints is not a problem, and the relevance of duality.  Very nice!

Comment: I think this answer doesn't address the question, which seems to be about how the complexity of solving the Subset Sum Problem for a given set $S$ depends on $\alpha(S)$.   And BTW, instead of Ellipsoid, can't one just use max-flow (and min-cut) to find the maximum anti-chain?  See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154320/min-cut-max-flow-rightarrow-dilworths-theorem)...